# Open application from google map URL

Tags: android, android-intent

Hello to open Application from URL i have code below

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
            <data android:host="maps.google.com" android:scheme="http"></data>
        </intent-filter>
```

URL is below

```
   https://maps.google.com/maps?q=70.005540,-111.000050
```

and to get Data in activity below is my code

```
   Uri data = getIntent().getData();
        if (data != null) {
            txtView.setText(data.getPath());
        }
```

My problem is when i click on above URL my application is not opening....

Comment: Shouldn't the android:scheme be "https"?

Comment: Are you opening it in a webview? are you trying to show it in a map inside the app?

Comment: no from mail i got link and from that link i want to open app...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your xml  code with below code

```
   <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
            <data android:host="maps.google.com" android:scheme="https"></data>
        </intent-filter>
```

it will work, i have tested

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in order to open the link in a webview.

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```